# Нужен генератор HEX 64 из реликтового излучения или белого шума

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пришла идея сделать генератор HEX 64, но нужно чтобы на эту генерацию повлиял внешний фактор.
Например реликтовое излучение вселенной или белый шум случайный.

Как это должно выглядеть на схеме?

Запуск *.py

inputsignal =  Берутся случайные частоты реликтового излучения или белого шума

BIN = Переводим inputsignal в двоичный код

Result = Двоичный код переводим в 16 систему c длинной 64 символа

Выводим результат

print(Result)

> c96d86bc2eafd8a8946c430a3112e3f23a895ec2c58b0ee5ec6086b459ebc8f1

Можно ли повлиять на генерацию таким способом, а не способами по умолчанию?

Помогите кто знает как это реализовать, можно с примерами.
Спасибо.

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить, как вы себе представляете ловлю реликтового излучения из python? (Мне действительно интересно)

Comment: @wololo, нужен телек на ЭЛТ, когда он не настроен на канале, то тот белый шум, что на экране - это по большей части реликтовое (во всяком случае раньше так было, сейчас из-за значительно возросшего кол-ва источников излучения вклад реликтового может и сильно снизился по сравнению с другими шумами)

Comment: @BTC MAKER, вроде как в современных процессорах уже есть честные генераторы случайных чисел (основаны на тепловом шуме), в c++ через stl библиотеки доступ к ним есть, думаю в питоне тоже самое - надо просто выбрать правильный источник случайных чисел

Comment: @Zhihar Спасибо я с Вами согласен, но мне захотелось свой генератор создать со своими внешними факторами, например можно ли сгенерировать белый шум в файл и из этого файла брать данные на вход, в качестве генерации? Если такое можно, не подскажите как можно реализовать?

Comment: "Случайности не случайны". Раньше я помню на каких-то сайтах просили мышкой подвигать и на основе этих данных генерили случайный пароль )

Comment: @BTC MAKER, конечно вы можете сгенерировать файл строго случайных чисел (это кстати можно проверить вычислив распределение, которое должно быть строго нормальным), но проблема то будет в другом - с какой позиции в файле начать получать эти числа :))) а вот это тоже придется получать с генератора (ну или как раньше делали - завязывать на текущее время)